# How does 'continue' act in 'for', which in another 'for'?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, continue

Let's say I have such code:

```
for (...;...;...){
     for (...;...;...){
          if (...){
               ...
               continue;
               ...
          }
      }
}
```

*('...' is some piece of code, doesn't really matter what)*

**When program gets to the 'continue', does it come back to the outer or inner for?**

Comment: inner for loop.

Answer (score 2):

The inner one. It's always the innermost loop. Many languages give you a way like "break 2" / "continue 2" to jump two levels and go on with the outer.

Comment: So with continue you go to the top of either 'while' or 'for', that's 'the closest' to you, 'the most inside' it can be?

Comment: The closest to you, yes, exactly. You can start going upwards with your caret from the "continue" and the first loop you hit is where it will jump.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following way

```
for (...;...;...){
     for (...;...;...){
          if (...){
               ...
               goto continue;
               ...
          }
      continue:;
      }
}
```

According to the C Standard (6.8.6.2 The continue statement)

> 2 A continue statement causes a jump to the loop-continuation portion
>   of the **smallest enclosing iteration statement**; that is, to the end
>   of the loop body. More precisely, in each of the statements

```
while (/* ... */) 
{ 
    /* ... */ 
    continue; 
    /* ... */ 
    contin: ; 
}

do 
{ 
    /* ... */ 
    continue; 
    /* ... */ 
    contin: ; 
} while (/* ... */);

for (/* ... */) 
{ 
    /* ... */ 
    continue; 
    /* ... */ 
    contin: ; 
}
```

> unless the continue statement shown is in an enclosed iteration
>   statement (in which case it is interpreted within that statement), it
>   is equivalent to goto contin;.

Comment: So if there was one more 'for' it would go to the most outer one? Or did you mean the program continues where you wrote 'continue'?

Comment: @AniaZdanowicz A continue statement passes the control to the smallest enclosing iteration statement.